# C++ classes link error s

Tags: c++, class, hyperlink

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class table
{
    int size;
    int priority;

    public:
    table(int s=0, int p=0):size(s),priority(p){}
    virtual void print();
};

class stud_table: public table
{
    char *name;
    int gr;

    public:
        void print(){ cout <<"students table"<<endl; }
        ~stud_table(){ delete []name; }
};

class asp_table: public table
{
    char *thesis;
};


int main()
{
  table t;
  stud_table st;
  table *tp=&st;

  tp = new asp_table();
  stud_table *stp = &st;

  cout << "Program" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

/*
Why I get link errors: 
Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall table::print(void)" (?print@table@@UAEXXZ)

*/

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't think it's a simple duplicated question. It seems to be a bug of the complier what op used, [clang](http://rextester.com/RDFD88926) runs it well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is enough clear: member function `print` in class `table` is declared but not defined.

Comment: Seems [clang](http://rextester.com/RDFD88926) doen't complain about it.

Comment: @songyuanyao It seems is implementation defined.

Comment: It help to fix the problem